# Density operator : is $\hat{\rho}=|\psi \rangle \langle \psi|$ the same as $\hat{\rho} = \sum_{i} \delta (x-x_i)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, density-operator, dirac-delta-distributions

I have just begun to learn about the density operator/matrix. I have learnt that for a state $|\psi\rangle=\sum c_i |u_i\rangle$ written in terms of some basis set {$| u_i\rangle$}, the corresponding density operator is defined to be:
$$\hat{\rho}\equiv |\psi \rangle \langle \psi|$$
It is immediately clear to me that in this form, the operator $\hat{\rho}$ as defined above will contain all the information that the corresponding ket $|\psi\rangle$ will contain. This can easily be seen if we write out the matrix of $\hat{\rho}$ : The matrix elements will contain all the coefficients present in the expansion of $|\psi\rangle$ in the $u_i$ basis and so the matrix will contain all the information about the state that the ket contains.

But now in my reading, I have often seen the density operator defined as
$$\hat{\rho} \equiv \sum_i\delta(x-x_i)$$
for a many particle system. Are these two definitions somehow equivalent? That is, is the second derivative perhaps simply a many particle generalization of the first? I have issues accepting this since its not at all clear to me how $\hat{\rho} \equiv \sum_i\delta(x-x_i)$ could contain all the information of the state in the same way that $\hat{\rho}\equiv |\psi \rangle \langle \psi|$ does.

So I guess I could summarize my question as: Are these two definitions equivalent and if so, how would we derive the one from the other? Any help on this would be most appreciated!

Comment: Please give a reference for the definition of $\hat\rho$. Usually, this is the definition of the single-particle density (operator) $n(x)$ of a system of $N$ (identical) particles.

Comment: @Jakob Sure, the second definition is used in Griffiths 3rd edition pg 205, problem 5.7. The first definition is used here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix but also in the afterward (chp 12) of Griffiths 3rd edition

Comment: Sorry, with $\hat \rho$ I of course meant the second definition. This makes no reference to any state $\psi$ (quite in contrast to the first definition); further, the second depends on $x$ (or $\hat x$) while the first does not... For example, take any state $\varphi$ orthogonal to $\psi$. Then the expectation value of the operator in the first definition is zero, while the expectation value of the operator of the second definition is a function of $x$ (generally non-zero).

Comment: Thanks, okay so is it then fair to say that they are both totally different concepts but are unfortunately often referred to by the same name?